# Getting an error when trying to deploy a smart contract from another smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat, evm, solidity-0.8.x

This is my smart contract

```
  contract Pool{
        constructor(
       address _baseToken,
       address _quotetoken,
       uint _sellTax,
       uint _buyTax
   ) {
       quotetoken = ERC20(_quotetoken);//these are already initiated variables within the code
       basetoken = ERC20(_baseToken);
       poolName = string.concat(basetoken.name(), quotetoken.name());
       sellTax = _sellTax;
       buyTax = _buyTax;
   }

}

 contract swap {
   Pool newPool;

   function createPool(
       address _basetoken,
       address _quotetoken,
       uint _sellTax,
       uint _buyTax
   ) external returns (Pool) {
       newPool = new Pool(_basetoken, _quotetoken, _sellTax, _buyTax);
      
    return newPool;
    }
```

i get an " EVM revert error" when i try to call the createPool method in the swap contract on both remix and hardhat , and i don't understand remix debugging interface ,pls what part of the code is faulty ?

Comment: Maybe `basetoken.name()` or quotetoken don't work. Try commenting out that line, and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is my trial code, it can be created correctly, there is no problem, and the two contracts that need to ensure the parameters exist. Because you need to call the name function of the erc20 contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Pool {
    ERC20 public quotetoken;
    ERC20 public basetoken;
    string public poolName;
    uint256 public sellTax;
    uint256 public buyTax;

    constructor(
        address _baseToken,
        address _quotetoken,
        uint256 _sellTax,
        uint256 _buyTax
    ) {
        quotetoken = ERC20(_quotetoken); //these are already initiated variables within the code
        basetoken = ERC20(_baseToken);
        poolName = string.concat(basetoken.name(), quotetoken.name());
        sellTax = _sellTax;
        buyTax = _buyTax;
    }
}

contract swap {
    Pool public newPool;

    event NewPool(address _newPool);

    function createPool(
        address _basetoken,
        address _quotetoken,
        uint256 _sellTax,
        uint256 _buyTax
    ) external returns (Pool) {
        newPool = new Pool(_basetoken, _quotetoken, _sellTax, _buyTax);
        emit NewPool(address(newPool));
        return newPool;
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually solved the problem and it was in the pool contract ,it seems that  the storage variables are already saved before the constructor is run cus one of my storage variables was quoteoken.balanceOf() and when I commented that line it's worked ,so the problem was not from the constructor but the body of the contract